# url coding in rails to generate a post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Consider i have the following url

```
http://myworkspace-myusername.c9users.io/?#/bookings
```

and the application works correctly.
and my rake routes are this:

```
 match '*all' => 'application#cors_preflight', via: :options
  post "/bookings", :to => "bookings#create"
```

The question is, does the `?#` infered as a post method?

Comment: nope.. you underlying JS is making a post request to `http://myworkspace-myusername.c9users.io/bookings` to check this  you can simply use `postman` to verify.. `?#` you see there is some js frontend framework doing its `routing` stuff.. my guess would be Angular or backbone